# Converter String para valor monetário em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, string, valor-monetário

Como converter o resultado de uma multiplicação dentro de uma `string` para exibir como Real?

O valor do `bol.ValorBoleto` é carregado um pouco antes.

A *data annotation*: `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]` não funciona.

Tentei diversas formas e não consegui.

Meu código está assim:

```
[Display(Name = "IRPJ")]
[ReadOnly(true)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public string IRPJ { get; set; }

public BoletoBancario GerarBoletoBradesco(BoletoModel bol, string txtIrpj)
{
   decimal irpj;

   irpj = Convert.ToDecimal(txtIrpj);

   bol.IRPJ = "IRPJ " + irpj + "%" + " - " + Convert.ToString(bol.ValorBoleto * irpj);

   Instrucao objInst3 = new Instrucao(237);
   objInst3.Descricao = bol.IRPJ;
}
```

Comment: Este código não faz sentido, tem algoritmo dentro da classe e fora de métodos? Coloque algo que funcione pra gente ver como está. Você está pegando uma variável `irpj` que apareceu do nada. Você está tentando aplicar uma formatação de número em algo que é composto por palavras. Esta é a intenção mesmo?

Comment: @bigown, não só está dentro de uma classe a propriedade, coloquei tudo junto pra ver onde estou usando. Essa variavel irpj está vindo como parametro.

Comment: Do jeito que está, tá solto na classe, muda pra ver como fez de verdade. Este código nem compila.

Comment: @bigown, mudei um pouco, vê se dá pra entender. Preciso exibir o resultado dessa multiplicação dentro dessa string no formato de real.

Comment: Agora ficou mais compreensível. Mas qual é o problema? Você pode fazer este parâmetro `txtIrpj` ser um número? A propriedade pode ser `Decimal`? Não faz sentido você formatar uma `string`.

Comment: Então, é que eu preciso exibir tipo assim "IRPJ 3% - 15,30". Isso eu vou exibir em um boleto. O txtIrpj é um valor de entrada.

Comment: E qual é o problema que está acontecendo?

Comment: Não está convertendo, está mostrando tipo  689,2210. No caso, no excel esse valor é R$6,89

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tem uma propriedade que terá a *string* montada manualmente não tem porque usar um atributo de formatação de número, então não precisa disto:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
```

Este atributo é ótimo se você tem um número simples e não um texto, como é o que você guarda na propriedade. Ainda que eu tenho minhas dúvidas se deveria ter um texto aí, mas sem um contexto mais completo não posso afirmar.

O cálculo está errado, já que é uma porcentagem, tem que dividir por 100. E a formatação do número precisa ser feita na montagem da *string*.

```
bol.IRPJ = "IRPJ " + irpj + "%" + " - " + $"{bol.ValorBoleto * irpj / 100):c}";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ConvertType.cs).

Talvez a formatação precisa ser um pouco diferente disto, talvez preciso informar a cultura, mas com as informações fornecidas eu não consigo fazer uma mais exata.

Pode ser também que o parâmetro `txtIrpj` precise de um tratamento dependendo de como ele vem mas não tenho como saber só com as informações fornecidas. Informações externas sempre deveriam ser verificadas se está em conformidade com o que se espera, se é um número válido.

Comment: a entrada que vem nesse txtIrpj é porcentagem.

Comment: Funcionou. Eu tinha esquecido de dividir por 100. Obrigado.