# Problema para enviar valores do tipo 11,50 para banco de dados SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com um problema de formatação de valores do tipo R$ quando envio para o banco de dado 11,50 no banco de dado fica do tipo 1150.

Esse condigo é do botão de enviar para o banco de dado tem uma classe de gestão de banco de dados `cl_GestorBD`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl_GestorBD gestor = new cl_GestorBD(true);
            int id_produto = gestor.ID_DISPONIVEL("compras", "id_compra");
            List<cl_GestorBD.SQLParametro> parametro = new List<cl_GestorBD.SQLParametro>();
            parametro.Add(new cl_GestorBD.SQLParametro("@atualizacao", DateTime.Now));

        string PRODUTO;
        int QTY;
        decimal VALOR_UNID;
        decimal VALOR_TOTAL;

        try
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem caixa in listCaixa.Items)
            {

                PRODUTO = caixa.SubItems[0].Text;
                QTY = Convert.ToInt32(caixa.SubItems[1].Text);
                VALOR_UNID = Convert.ToDecimal(caixa.SubItems[2].Text);
                VALOR_TOTAL = Convert.ToDecimal(caixa.SubItems[3].Text);

                query = "INSERT INTO compras VALUES ('" + id_produto + "','" + lblID.Text + "', '" + PRODUTO + "', '" + QTY + "', '" + VALOR_UNID + "', '" + VALOR_TOTAL + "',@atualizacao)";
                gestor.EXE_NON_QUERY(query, parametro);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Registrado com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERRO " + erro.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tente trocar a virgula por ponto antes de enviar para o banco

Comment: Por favor, compartilhe o trecho de código que voce está utilizando,  quais tipos está usando, double, real, etc, normalmente como o Matheus falou ponto por vírgula, mas tem que ver como está seu código pra evitar ficar fazendo replace e fazer da forma correta.

Comment: Isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81237/101. Claro, a solução pode ser outra, mas se você tem 1150, e quer 11,50, é só dividir por 100. Agora, se o problema é que está recebendo o dado de forma errada talvez seja mais interessante consertar isto.

Comment: de uma olhada ai acabei de atualizar as informações em cima

Comment: eu mudei o tipo no banco de dado de money para numeric(15,2) so que agora quando envior aparece uma mensagem de erro: Date conversion failed [OLE DB status value (if-know) = 0 ]

Comment: agora eu mudei o tipo de numeric(15,2) do banco de dado para int, os dado enviar e não da erro, so que o valor 11,50 ele fica como 115

Comment: Não mude nada pra inteiro, se o dado tem o tipo correspondente no banco de dados faça do jeito que tem que ser feito, já pegou ai uma quebra de número, que vai gerar um grande problema, cuidado. Coloque no banco de dados decimal ou correspondente e faça a conversão no código e pronto, faltou falar qual é o seu banco e o seu código pela atualização tem grande problemas, um deles é não utilizar `Parameters` ...

Comment: @RaphaelShembek Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Sem falar nos nomes de variáveis que não seguem o [estilo recomendado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101), o código tem alguns problemas:

Não converta dados que você não tem certeza que estão corretos. O [`Convert` gerará erro na aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101) quando isso ocorrer. Teste se o dado está correto com [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

> ```
> query = "INSERT INTO compras VALUES ('" + id_produto + "','" + lblID.Text + "', '" + PRODUTO + "', '" + QTY + "', '" + VALOR_UNID + "', '" + VALOR_TOTAL + "',@atualizacao)";
> ```

Este código é extremamente inseguro. [É mais ou menos assim que se faz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221464/101).

A forma como está gravando pode violar a atomicidade e consistência do banco de dados, só não garanto porque não sei os requisitos.

[Sempre que captura `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101), exceto quando é muito experiente, está procurando uma solução mágica para os problemas. Escolha que exceção que tratar e faça um tratamento adequado, o que foi feito não é útil.

O tipo correto é `Money` mesmo. E precisa indicar o tipo no código, algo assim:

```
new SqlParameter("@Valor", SqlDbType.Money)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Money.cs).

Tem algumas coisas que não parecem fazer sentido, mas vai saber... Por exemplo `SubItems` me parece esquisito.

Tem outros problemas que não fazem o código ficar errado, mas que não é assim que se costuma fazer.

Pode ter mais algum problema que não está claro no código, inclusive na entrada do texto.

Answer (score -1):

Deixe o campo no banco como numeric(18,2) e tente assim:

Obs.: Não estou com C# aqui para testar, talvez você precise mudar alguma coisinha ali na formatação

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl_GestorBD gestor = new cl_GestorBD(true);
            int id_produto = gestor.ID_DISPONIVEL("compras", "id_compra");
            List<cl_GestorBD.SQLParametro> parametro = new List<cl_GestorBD.SQLParametro>();
            parametro.Add(new cl_GestorBD.SQLParametro("@atualizacao", DateTime.Now));

        string PRODUTO;
        int QTY;
        string VALOR_UNID;
        string VALOR_TOTAL;

        try
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem caixa in listCaixa.Items)
            {

                PRODUTO = caixa.SubItems[0].Text;
                QTY = Convert.ToInt32(caixa.SubItems[1].Text);
                VALOR_UNID = caixa.SubItems[2].Text.ToString("N2"); /*ou ToString("0.##");*/
                VALOR_TOTAL = caixa.SubItems[3].Text.ToString("N2");

                query = "INSERT INTO compras VALUES ('" + id_produto + "','" + lblID.Text + "', '" + PRODUTO + "', '" + QTY + "', '" + VALOR_UNID + "', '" + VALOR_TOTAL + "',@atualizacao)";
                gestor.EXE_NON_QUERY(query, parametro);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Registrado com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERRO " + erro.Message);
        }
    }
```